# Signed request to API Gateway with resource policy results in user: anonymous error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I'm currently trying to secure an API Gateway with a resource policy.  I have other REST APIs using API Gateway which need to perform HTTP requests to the API Gateway with the resource policy.  I'll call the resource-policy secured API Service A, and a separate API which needs to call it Service B.

For now I'd like to restrict access to Service A to services within my account.  For the resource policy on Service A I have:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:XXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXX:root"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:XXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Deny policy NotPrincipal property is the same as the Allow policy Principal statement, with the intention of allowing any traffic from my account, and explicitly denying traffic from anything that is not my account (at least that's how I think it works?).

In order to test Service A with the resource policy I wrote up a little mock of the signed request protocol that Service B seems like it will need to implement, using the `requests-aws4auth` library (I've also tried almost exactly the same thing with `aws-requests-auth` with the same result):

```
def try_auth_request():
    import boto3
    from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
    import requests

    session = boto3.Session()
    credentials = session.get_credentials()
    region = 'XXXXXXX'

    awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, 'execute-api')
    response = requests.get('https://XXXXXXX.execute-api.XXXXX.amazonaws.com/dev/', auth=awsauth)
    print(response.text)
```

When I run the test I get the following 403 response text:

```
{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:*******:***********:******/dev/GET/ with an explicit deny"}
```

I checked the credentials being added to the request via the debugger and they are indeed credentials for a user in my account. I also tried using my root credentials with the same failure. The required `x-amz-date` header is there, the `Authorization` header looks like the examples of AWS HMAC signatures I've seen. Whatever is going on it seems like the authorization signature I'm providing on the HTTP request is not properly conferring the associated IAM user to the resource policy it gets checked. I would not be surprised if my process is flawed, particularly the resource policy itself. Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: I should mention that these API Gateways and their backing Lambdas are not contained with a VPC.

Comment: Have you set up authorization type to IAM? This is only supported with IAM. Then, check if the user whose credentials are used has the permission to invoke execute-api operation. I would also remove either the explicit `Deny` or `Allow` statement.

Comment: @Paul Michalik - Hey thanks for the response.  I did try setting the authorization type to IAM and the resource policy worked with that.  I guess what I was hoping was that I would be able to use IAM auth for my internal services, and then custom Lambda auth for our browser-based application, but it's becoming apparent that that may not be an option. Kind of looking like I'll have to use the same auth protocol for internal and external services

Comment: Hm, what exactly is the problem? You can implement the authorization exactly as you described - actually this is one of the intended use-cases. I am currently testing all feasible alternatives for similar scenarios. For internal services, I would have preferred the resource policy based authentication, my preferred method was VPC whitelisting. However, this only works for private APIs and comes with additional  problems and cost.

Comment: I think the issue may be that after services authenticating with signed requests get past the resource policy our lambda authorizer is failing auth whenever there isn't a JWT token... maybe the lambda needs to just return an empty policy? Right now it's just returning a failure message.